# How to build a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to compile a hello world module given over [here](http://www.linux-support.com/cms/en/component/content/article/3-articles/71-building-and-running-kernel-modules-linux-26?directory=14)

I have followed the following step.

1. Downloaded Linux kernel 2.6.35-rc5
2. extracted to directory /general/source/linux
3. Complied the entire kernel.
4. created a dir test in the linux folder.
5. Created and complied a hello world module as mentioned there.

when I run the insmod command, I get this error

```
insmod: error inserting 'hello.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

How do I sort out this error?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the mistake that you are making is the kernel version.

First try

```
uname -r
```

You would get the kernel version. The downloaded version mostly likely won't be the kernel version of your system. 
So change the make file to

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

.PHONY: build clean

build:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
else

$(info Building with KERNELRELEASE = ${KERNELRELEASE})
obj-m :=    hello.o

endif
```

Make sure the tabs are in the order as mentioned in the above script.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel module must match the running kernel. If you want to install this specific module, for example, you'd need to also install the kernel that you've built.

Normally, you'd not build the kernel on your own and use a pre-built version that matches your distribution's kernel. Look for a `kernel-headers` package in your distribution's repository.

Comment: `kernel*devel*` in some cases, because something with `headers` is often `/usr/include/linux`, which is reserved for userspace.

Comment: Ok ... now how to resolve this ? any step-by-step guide for newbies

Comment: You pretty much just set `KERNELDIR` in the Makefile to where kernel-headers was installed instead of your custom built kernel. Try [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html) for Ubuntu.